# How does Amazon ensure its drones are not shot down or captured when in service

Tags: uav

If Amazon plans to deliver packages using drones, how does it ensure the drones reach their destination safely and come back? Won't thieves be able to easily steal packages and drones by shooting them down? What about threat from birds like falcons?

Comment: Parachute delivery from sufficient heights can alleviate your concerns for sufficiently durable goods.

Comment: Photo surveillance?

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* nk379, but I'm afraid that highly speculative questions like this really aren't a good fit for a stack exchange site, since we have no idea how Amazon might react to one of it's drones being interfered with. In general, we prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*. Take a look at [ask] and [about] for more information on how stack exchange works. Also, the [*Robotics* question checklist](http://meta.robotics.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) has good advice on how to write a good question.

Answer (score 0):

Mister Frauke Zeller is a researcher in the field of "how the environment reacts to robots". He questions about how a robot have to be designed in a way that his human environment acts in a friendly or not so friendly manner. The best example is the hitchbot project, which was not a experiment on how to create a robot, but a study what people will do if they see such robot [Post-hitchBOT-ism](http://wi.mobilities.ca/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/wi_journal_10.1.5_zellersmith.pdf). There are also experiments in the wild, how birds are interacting with drones [DRONES UNDER ATTACK - Drone Fails](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZMnZ7RS88so).